# From CURL to AJAX XMLHttp

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to convert the curl code from an API called TextRazor to AJAX XMLHttp because of platform limitations. I have tried many solutions from similar questions by the community but can't seem to get any data back or just a "400: Bad Request". If it matters, from the documentation calling the API looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "x-textrazor-key: YOUR_API_KEY" \
-d "extractors=entities,entailments" \
-d "text=Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell off..." \
https://api.textrazor.com/
```

My current AJAX XMLHttp code looks like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://api.textrazor.com/";
var params = "extractors=entities&text=Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell...";
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);

xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-textrazor-key", "YOUR_API_KEY");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xhttp.responseText);
}
}

xhttp.send(params);
```

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the [same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500).

Because you are making a cross-origin request and adding a custom header, the browser is making a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) before it makes the request you are asking for.

The server you are making the request to is not prepared to respond to an OPTIONS request so it throws a 400 back at you.

To fix this:

- They should support CORS
- They should provide an alternative means to get the data such as JSONP (not recommended, we have CORS now)
- You should not make the request directly to their server from the browser